# Maven attempting to deploy to localhost instead of remote server

Tags: java, tomcat, maven, tomcat7, maven-tomcat-plugin

This is my `pom.xml` build configuration:

```xml
<build>
    <finalName>cfwd</finalName>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
              <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.3.2</version>
              <configuration>
                <source>1.6</source>
                <target>1.6</target>
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
              <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>2.0</version>        
              <configuration>
                <url>http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/manager/text</url>
                <server>cifServer</server>
                <path>/cfwd</path>
                <addContextWarDependencies>true</addContextWarDependencies>
                <addWarDependenciesInClassloader>true</addWarDependenciesInClassloader>        
              </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
</build>
```

where `http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080` is the remote server IP.

When I try to deploy via `mvn tomcat:deploy` I get this error:

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal
>   org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy (default-cli) on
>   project cfwd: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Server returned HTTP
>   response code: 403 for URL:
>   `http://localhost:8080/manager/deploy?path=%2Fcfwd&war=` -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to
>   execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy
>   (default-cli) on project cfwd: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager

where it looks like maven is attempting to deploy to `localhost:8080` rather than the remote server IP. Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to execute `mvn tomcat7:deploy` (note the '7') in order to trigger the plugin you've configured.

See [this page](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html) for more information about the available goals.

Answer (score 1):

403 means Forbidden.

Check with the [official documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/maven-plugin-2.0/tomcat7-maven-plugin/deploy-mojo.html) in order to configure authentication to the Tomcat manager (parameters Server, password, username).

Duncan Jones is right : you are not executing the correct plugin : use tomcat7.

Comment: +1ed, but will mark Duncan's answer as correct as it came before yours. Cheers!