# Tomcat7 Maven Plugin appears to not be picking up url in configuration

Tags: maven, plugins, tomcat7

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Maven attempting to deploy to localhost instead of remote server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725945/maven-attempting-to-deploy-to-localhost-instead-of-remote-server)

I have an interesting problem here.  I'm working in a Windows 7 Pro x64 environment using Maven - 3.0.4 and jdk 1.6

I have in my settings.xml for maven:

```
    <servers>
        <server>
            <id>LocalTomcatServer</id>
            <username>localTomcatAdmin</username>
            <password>password</password>
        </server>
    </servers>
```

In my tomcat-users.xml file I have defined:

```
    <tomcat-users>
        <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
        <role rolename="manager-script"/>
        <role rolename="admin"/>
        <user username="localTomcatAdmin" password="password" roles="manager-gui,manager-script,admin"/>
    </tomcat-users>
```

I have also created a pom-deploy.xml which is a parent of the pom.xml (resides at the same level) which contains the following plugin:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
        <configuration>
             <server>LocalTomcatServer</server>
         <path>/<path to deploy to></path>
         <port>8080</port>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```

For some reason that eludes me, when I run mvn -f pom-deploy.xml tomcat:deploy I get back the following output from maven.

```
    [INFO] BUILD FAILURE
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [INFO] Total time: 20.201s
    [INFO] Finished at: Wed Dec 12 09:00:21 EST 2012
    [INFO] Final Memory: 11M/149M
    [INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:tomcat-maven-plugin:1.1:deploy  (default-cli) on project <project name>: Cannot invoke Tomcat manager: Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for
    URL: http://localhost:8080/manager/deploy?path=%2FTripTixRX&war= -> [Help 1]
```

Every other life-cycle goal works.

the codehaus plugin is NOT configured for this project.  I have tried the org.codehaus.mojo plug in and set the to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/manager/html`

The output seems to be indicative to the url not getting parsed by the plug in, however, now that I have switched to the official tc7 plugin, I figured that would have alleviated the problem.

This almost indicates that maven is not using the configured plug in.  I've wiped out my .m2/repository and started over completely fresh.  Still no luck.  At this point, I started digging and found that it's not even downloading the tomcat7-maven-plugin.  I read a few comments on here regarding adding to the  in the settings.xml, which I reluctantly did.  That seems rather counter intuitive to me, but I wanted to eliminate all the possibilities. I added org.tomcat.apache.maven to the  in my settings.xml file for maven, rebuilt, and blamo, it works.

So at this point, I'm glad it works, but I'm mad.  Doesn't that completely remove the portability of this from one maven environment to another without modifying the maven settings.xml configuration per machine?  I shouldn't have to configure Maven for the project but the thought is that the configuration should reside completely in the pom for maximum portability.

Also I'm not sure if it's my settings or not, but there was no message about "Hey this plugin you configured wasn't found!"  I had to -X -e and drag my butt through the output log to even remotely get a glimpse of what the end issue 'might' be.

Getting it to work is never a  question, it's the WHY.  It seem that it has to be defined like this and from my standpoint, the project portability went right out the door.  Is this a result of my maven configuration or is this the norm?  Judging from reading other users posts about this, it appears that this is a normal thing in maven.  I guess the end result is "I'm glad I answered the question" but I'm more into the how and why mechanics.

EDIT:  The command I am running is:  mvn -f pom-deploy.xml -U -Dmaven.test.skip=true clean package tomcat7:deploy -X -e

Here is a snippet from the maven output that is still showing that there is no authentication server:

```
    [DEBUG] Configuring mojo org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.0:deploy from plugin realm ClassRealm[plugin>org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.0, parent: sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader@c22b29a]
    [DEBUG] Configuring mojo 'org.apache.tomcat.maven:tomcat7-maven-plugin:2.0:deploy'  with basic configurator -->
    [DEBUG]   (f) charset = ISO-8859-1
    [DEBUG]   (f) contextFile = `E:\workspace\<repo-name>\branches\<project name>-0.1\target\<project name>\META-INF\context.xml`
    [DEBUG]   (f) ignorePackaging = false
    [DEBUG]   (f) mode = war
    [DEBUG]   (f) packaging = war
    [DEBUG]   (f) path = /<project name>
    [DEBUG]   (f) update = false
    [DEBUG]   (f) url = http://localhost:8080/manager/html
    [DEBUG]   (f) version = 2.0
    [DEBUG]   (f) warFile = E:\workspace\<repo name>\branches\<Project name>-0.1\target\<project-name>.war
    [DEBUG] -- end configuration --
    [INFO] Deploying war to http://localhost:8080/<project name>
    [DEBUG] No server specified for authentication - using defaults
    Uploading: http://localhost:8080/manager/html/deploy?path=%2F<project name>
```

And with this, it's returning me the dreaded:  401 - Unauthorized

Comment: @Duncan Jones:  Here is the exact command I am running:  mvn -f pom-deploy.xml -U -Dmaven.test.skip=true clean package tomcat7:deploy -X -e > deploy2test.output

Comment: In that case I'm mistaken. You may wish to edit your question above as it doesn't show that.

Comment: @Duncan Jones: thanks for the tip, I did just that :: thumbs up ::

Comment: I've voting to re-open this, as I originally voted to close when I thought the answer was `tomcat7` related. Sadly you can't undo a close vote!